# Why does file redirection succeed where cp/mv fail?

Tags: shell, amazon-eks

I'm trying to overwrite /etc/resolv.conf in a Docker container running Alpine Linux on EKS. Copy and move both fail:

```sh
~ # cp /tmp/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf 
cp: can't create '/etc/resolv.conf': File exists
~ # mv /tmp/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf 
mv: can't rename '/tmp/resolv.conf': Resource busy
```

But shell redirection succeeds, and preserves the inode:

```sh
~ # ls -li /etc/resolv.conf 
1412461 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root           131 Feb 17 20:45 /etc/resolv.conf
~ # cat /tmp/resolv.conf.1386 > /etc/resolv.conf 
~ # ls -li /etc/resolv.conf 
1412461 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root            39 Feb 18 19:17 /etc/resolv.conf
```

Why does redirection succeed on a busy file?

Comment: resolv.conf in docker is managed by docker. See for example `mount` output

Comment: Thanks, but my question is about redirection. Docker is a detail.

Comment: ? It's not. Because resolv.conf is mount -o bind by docker, you can't `cp` and `mv` it.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. My question is why does redirection succeed?

Comment: Redirection is opening an existing file (with O_TRUNC, in your usage mode) and modifying its contents, without changing the directory that contains the file. `mv` is replacing the existing directory entry with one pointing to a different inode. They're completely different operations.

Comment: I'd need to see a `strace` of the failed `cp` to know why it fails, but the `mv` is obvious on its face.

Comment: I'm glad you consider your question addressed, but I'm still curious about what your copy of `cp` is doing. :) -- any chance of gisting that strace?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy strace is not present in the image I'm using. Sorry.

Comment: That's where I reach for `sysdig` -- you only need to install it on the host, not in your containers at all, and it can trace any code running in any of them (or all of them at once).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirection doesn't *change the directory the file is contained in*, whereas `mv` does. This is critical when -- as here -- your "directory entry" is actually a mount point, where the kernel is overriding a directory entry and not letting the usual contents be exposed.

That is:

---

#### What `mv foo bar` does

```
mv foo bar
```

...is, at an operating system level, invoking the syscall `rename("foo", "bar")`, replacing the *directory entry* `bar` with the inode that the directory entry `foo` currently points at. It never opens or changes the preexisting `bar` file at all; the *only* thing it does is change the directory that previously contained that file to instead point at a different file in the entry with the same name.

---

#### What `echo hello > bar` does

By contrast, `echo hello >bar` isn't changing the *directory entry* at all; it's only changing the file that directory entry points at. Specifically, it's running `open("bar", O_TRUNC)`, and `write(<fdno>, "hello\n")` to the file descriptor that `open()` returned.

---

#### So, what's `cp` doing?

...that's a good question. *In general*, `cp` modifies the existing file in-place. You can test that as follows:

```
echo ORIGINAL > file1
ln file1 file2
echo REPLACED > file3
cp file3 file1
cat file2
```

If `cp` were replacing `file1` with a completely new file, then the inode that `file2` is associated with would be unchanged (containing "ORIGINAL"). That's not what happens, though -- `file2` is modified by the `cp` that only directly identified `file1` as its output file, changing that file to contain `REPLACED`.

I'd need to see the output of `strace cp /tmp/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` to diagnose the behavior described.